# Set Gather Widget Attribute from Set Variables Widget

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

Is it possible to set the Gather Input on Call widget timeout attribute from within a flow at runtime using a Set Variables widget? I have a Gather widget named gatherMenu and I have tried setting a preceding Set Variables widget Key to {{widgets.gatherMenu.timeout}} with a value of 10, but the subsequent gatherMenu timeout remains at the default of 5 during execution. I have also tried setting the Key to {{widgets.gatherMenu.parsed.timeout}} without success.

```
{
  "name": "setVariablesInitialize",
  "type": "set-variables",
  "transitions": [
    {
      "next": "gatherMenu",
      "event": "next"
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "variables": [
      {
        "value": "10",
        "key": "widgets.gatherMenu.parsed.timeout"
      }
    ],
    "offset": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 220
    }
  }
},
```